# Does any webhosting service that supports python also supports django?

Tags: python, django, web-hosting

I'm trying to learn python/django, these are installed on my desktop computer and all the examples run fine. My question is: If a webhosting service supports python (2.4), does the webhosting service supports django by default?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/), which is free and [includes Django](http://www.deck.cc/django_1.2_on_google_app_engine.html).

Comment: +1 App Engine is the best option, IMHO

Comment: Do they support stock Django yet, or do they still need a special fork?

Comment: @Ignacio, @Luke: http://www.deck.cc/django_1.2_on_google_app_engine.html

Comment: Google App Engine sounds nice, I'll give it a try,

Comment: I think the best way to get django on app engine is: http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine, this give support to most of the orm.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but if they only support Python via CGI then your application will be very, very slow. Best is WSGI, then FastCGI, then mod_python.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily.Many web hosting companies(shared) claim to offer django but this is a big lie.Case in point,a2hosting claims to have django but don't offer it;its disallowed.I tried to compile my own python and install django and found out that that path is also closed.

Django is memory intensive and will only work on vps and dedicated accounts.Web faction though is the only web host that wont lie to you.

Comment: If they don't have Python then they don't support it, and this whole question is moot.

Answer (score 0):

Try Fornex VPS. https://fornex.com/vds/ 
I use it and like very much. Month payment starts from 5 euros. And you can install apache 2 + wsgi.